# position subcaption within `subfigure` at the top (inset)

Tags: vertical-alignment, captions, subcaption

I've asked a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599304/position-subcaption-within-the-figure-inset) but I did not realize that the question and solution relied on the caption being positioned at the bottom.

Consider the following example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    % from `caption` documentation:
    % Please note that `position=top` does NOT mean that the caption is actually placed at the top of the figure or table
    % Instead the caption is usually placed where you place the `\caption` command.
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false,skip=-6pt,position=top}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \caption{}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \caption{}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package mentions options that are described in further detail in the [`caption` documentation](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/tree/master/doc). In the source, `\caption{}` should appear before `\includegraphics{...` to affect the ordering. Unfortunately, this has an unintended influence that the label is rendered below the figure, which means that the figure occludes it. In the example, I include a skip that partially occludes the labels:

[image]

How can I get captions positioned on the top, but within the figure? I am beginning to understand why [these answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128844/put-subfigure-labels-inside-figures-using-subfig-package) are so much more involved for captions placed within the top and not the bottom of the figure.

Comment: \caption begins and ends with a \par.  [skip=-6pt] is the culprit.  Lose the \captionsetulp, or at least learn how to use it correctly.

Comment: @JohnKormylo perhaps you misunderstood the question. I want the label to be set within the figure.

Answer (score 4):

The foreground must always be drawn **after** the background, which means raising the caption into position.  (If you were wondering, TikZ does layers in order automatically.)

`\caption` must go inside a `minipage`, `\parbox` or `\vbox`, and `\setbox0=\vbox{}` is the simplest way to put one inside a `\raisebox`.  The `\vbox` gets its width from the current environment.

You can tweak the `\raisebox` to change the location.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    % from `caption` documentation:
    % Please note that `position=top` does NOT mean that the caption is actually placed at the top of the figure or table
    % Instead the caption is usually placed where you place the `\caption` command.
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false,skip=0pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
      \setbox0=\vbox{\caption{}\label{fig:a}}% label uses local values
      \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}}% measure height
        \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% use horizontal overlap
        \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht1-\ht0}{\usebox0}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
      \setbox0=\vbox{\caption{}\label{fig:b}}% label uses local values
      \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-b}}% measure height
        \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% use horizontal overlap
        \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht1-\ht0}{\usebox0}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]